# Is it possible to globally set projection options for all queries in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, projection, mongojs

I don't usually want or need the "_id" field to be returned in my queries. So, for each query, I have to set:

`{ $projection: "_id": 0 }`

Is it possible to set this value globally so that any query executed will not include the "_id" field?

Comment: No there's no global projection option in MongoDB. Note that the `_id` field can be customized, as long as the values are unique across that collection. Why not utilize this fact and use the `_id` to store something meaningful?

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB you can't use any global projection if you don't want a _id field you can set `{_id:0}` in projection. If you use aggregation you can project `{"$project" : {"_id" : 0,...}}` your fields in an initial pipeline stage. because MongoDB every pipeline input is depending on the previous pipeline out.
[aggregation pipeline stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) , [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)